# Why my code is not showing the answer when i click button "Show Answer"

Tags: reactjs

EDIT: Add a new 'Show answer' button to display the correct answer to the question. The answer is not visible when the question is retrieved but is only displayed when the 'Show answer' button is pressed. Make only one fetch request / question and you can display the answer using conditional rendering, for example. HELP NEEDED

const Trivia = () => {

```
 const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState();
 const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = React.useState(false);


 const fetchQuestion = () => {
     fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
      setQuestion(data.results[0].question);
         
     });
   };

    const answerToggler = () => setShowAnswer(prevAns => !prevAns)
     React.useEffect(() => {
         fetchQuestion();
     }, []);
 
 return(

 <div>
 <p> {question}</p>
 <button onClick={fetchQuestion}>New Question</button>
 {showAnswer && <h3>Correct Answer</h3>} **<= This is just an example because i don't know what i put there**
<button onClick={answerToggler}>Show Answer </button> 
         
</div>
     );
```

};

The idea is that the code retrieves the answer to the question by pressing the "show answer" button using only one fetch request. It should look like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Please do these changings:

```
 const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState();
 const [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = React.useState(false);
 const [answer, setAnswer] = React.useState();
        
 const fetchQuestion = () => {
      setShowAnswer(false);
      fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
      setQuestion(data.results[0].question);              
 });
 };
            
const answerToggler = () => { 
      setShowAnswer(true);
      fetch("opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
            setAnswer(data.result[0].answer);/*I dont sure this be same you want*/
       });
     };
 React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchQuestion();
    }, []);
             
 return(
      <div>
       <p> {question}</p>
       <button onClick={fetchQuestion}>New Question</button>
       {showAnswer ? <h3>{answer}</h3> : ""}
       <button onClick={answerToggler}>Show Answer </button>        
      </div>
   );
 }
```

If this solves you problem, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working :(

Comment: @Laura what is the content of the object relevant to the answer/answers? Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think your logic to show the answer is not correct.

Change this:

`{showAnswer && <h3>Correct Answer</h3>}`

For this

`{showAnswer ? (<h3>Correct Answer</h3>) : ""}`

This is a conditional operator which is like an if. It is saying if(showAnswer === true) show the correct answer, else dont show anything

Comment: yeah.. i know but i don't know what to do :/

Comment: I explained it better in the edit

Comment: I tried that one but its not working.. it have to give the answer for the question and not "Correct Answer"

Comment: What does it do when you press the button?

Comment: Check if your showAnswer state is changing with a `console.log(showAnswer)`

Comment: it says "correct answer" and it should give an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Well it's saying correct answer because you are printing that in a `<h3>Correct answer</h3>` To show the correct answer you have to extract it from the fetch request I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241904/discussion-between-joaquin-varela-and-laura).

Comment: Yes i know but the code should provide an answer to the question asked and retrieve the answer from this link: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1

I typed that "correct answer" as an example because I don't know how to get an answer from the website

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch returns something like this:

```
{
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Film",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "Which former Star Trek actor directed Three Men and a Baby (1987)?",
      "correct_answer": "Leonard Nimoy",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "William Shatner",
        "George Takei",
        "James Doohan"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The correct answer is right there. When you do the fetch in your code you are saving just the question in your state. You could try to save the whole response and then filter it.

like this: `setQuestion(data.results[0])` and then you can access the question and the answer from that state. like this:

`<p>{question.question}</p>`

`<p>{question.correct_answer}</p>`

Comment: idk what you mean :(

Comment: you should do a react course

Comment: Yeah.. im studying at the moment :D im student and its my second year so yep im not a pro... Sorry for that.. :D

Comment: And that's why i ask for help because i'm only training .. sorry i'm not a pro right away :))